# Is there a better solution than deleting the Android folder to rebuild in a ReactJS project?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, cross-platform, emulation

Is there any way to rebuild android folder in reactjs[not react native] project folder project folder and update in android studio code, so that to run the changes done in index/app.js files reflect in emulator as well.
I tried to delete the previous android folder and then build again as I got this solution on internet. but is there any proper solution for this.?

Thanks in advance for your valuable time and revert.

Is there any way to rebuild android folder in reactjs?